# jQuery Autocomplete only works with UPPER CASE

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a WordPress site with some custom PHP coding. I do not know what has changes, but I have noticed that my autocomplete field is not working properly any more.

I have a form field, where I type in player name and once three characters are entered, I retrieve a list of possible matches from database to choose from. I have noticed today, that it is still working but only in case I use all UPPER CASE letters when typing into player2 field. If I use regular letters, I always get first 10 records from database, regardless of the search term. Strange!!!

Here is my form jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#player2').autocomplete({
            source:'/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/suggest-pid2.php', 
            minLength:2,
            autoFocus: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                    // Set autocomplete element to display the label
                    this.value = ui.item.playername;

                    // Store value in hidden field
                    $('#PlayerID').val(ui.item.value);

                    // Prevent default behaviour
                    return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my search code to get records back from db:

```
<?php

// get search term (player name or surname)
$term = $_REQUEST['term'];

if (isset($term)) {    


    $dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'un', 'pw') or die( mysql_error() );
    mysql_select_db('db');
    $sql = "SELECT " .
            "P.PlayerID, P.PlayerName, P.PlayerSurname, C.CityName, " .
            "DATE_FORMAT(P.PlayerDateOfBirth, '%Y') AS PlayerYearOfBirth " .
        "FROM players P " .
            "LEFT JOIN cities C ON C.CityID = P.CityID " .
        "WHERE P.PlayerName LIKE '" . $term . "%' " .
            "OR P.PlayerSurname LIKE '" . $term . "%' " . 
        "ORDER BY P.PlayerName, P.PlayerSurname ASC LIMIT 0,10;";


    // Important - UTF-8!!!
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $dblink);
    $rs = mysql_query($sql, $dblink);
    $data = array();
    if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) ) {    
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {        
            $data[] = array(            
            'label' => $row['PlayerName'] .' '. $row['PlayerSurname'] .' ('. $row['PlayerYearOfBirth'] .'), '. $row['CityName'] ,            
            'value' => $row['PlayerID'] ,            
            'playername' => $row['PlayerName'] .' '. $row['PlayerSurname']        
            );    
            }}
    echo json_encode($data);
    flush();

}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the file from scratch and now it is working. I don't have any idea what was wrong, but it looks like php file was corrupted. Working now.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your string to uppercase to make the query

Comment: I have tried, but this is not working. It looks like if search term is entered in lower case it is recognized as empty string.